# Makefile target with variables not working as expected

Tags: variables, makefile, target

I would like to untar a file, if the files it contains have not been extracted. If I specify the target without the variable % then it works. However, I am not sure how to make this work with %. There is also dependency on files and its corresponding tar compressed file ending with .tgz. Here is what I have so far. I can do `make T2`, but not `make T1` or `make T3`. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here.  Thanks.

```
TAR_FILE1 := ../a_files.tgz 
EXTRACT_DIR1 := ../ 
EXTRACT_LIST1 :=        \

TAR_FILE2 := ../b_files.tgz 
EXTRACT_DIR2 := ../ 
EXTRACT_LIST2 :=        \

F := ../b_files/b.v
TF := ../b_files.tgz 
DIR := ../ 
ET := 

IP_EXTRACT: $(RTL_FILES%) 

$(RTL_FILES%): $(IP_TAR_FILE%)   
    @echo -e "\nTarget $@ with $*:"
    gtar zxvfmC $(IP_TAR_FILE%) $(IP_EXTRACT_DIR%) $(IP_EXTRACT_LIST%)

$(F): $(TF)   
    @echo -e "\nTarget $@ with $*:"
    gtar zxvfmC $(TF) $(DIR) $(ET)

$(FILES%): $(TAR_FILE%)   
    @echo -e "\nTarget $@ with $*:"
    gtar zxvfmC $(TAR_FILE%) $(EXTRACT_DIR%) $(EXTRACT_LIST%)

FILES1 := \
../a_files/a.v  \
../a_files/a1.v \
../a_files/a2.v

FILES2 := ../b_files/b.v ../b_files/b1.v ../b_files/b2.v

print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)


T1: $(FILES%)
T2: $(F)
T3: $(FILES1)

clean:
    rm -rf ../a_files ../b_files
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` make wildcard is not what you apparently think. In your Makefile it is almost everywhere a regular character, part of make variable names. For instance, when you write:

```
$(RTL_FILES%): $(IP_TAR_FILE%)
```

the strings between `()` are variable names. And as you probably don't have such variables defined, they expand as the empty string.

The only exception is the `print-%` rule, where it is correctly used to form a pattern rule. For the same reason all your uses of the `$*` automatic variable are probably wrong: it always expands as the empty string. Moreover, your question is incomplete because you do not explain what variables `RTL_FILES`, `IP_TAR_FILE`, `FILES`, `TAR_FILE`... are.

Anyway, if you want to "*untar a file if the files it contains has not been extracted*" there are several possibilities. The following assumes that you use GNU make and that your `../a_files.tgz` tarball expands as:

```
a_files
├── a
└── b
    └── b
```

It also assumes that you do not have file or directory names with spaces, tabs, special characters...

#### A simple solution

Let's start with a simple solution where you want to untar `../a_files.tgz` if and only if the `../a_files` directory does not exist. Else you consider that the tarball has already been extracted.

```
.PHONY: all

all: | ../a_files

../a_files:
    tar -C .. -xvf ../a_files.tgz
```

Note the [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) of the `all` target, introduced by `|`. It tells make that only the existence of the prerequisite matters, not its last modification time. In most cases it is needed when prerequisites are directories.

Demonstration:

```
$ make
tar -C .. -xvf ../a_files.tgz
a_files/
a_files/b/
a_files/b/b
a_files/a
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

#### A more complex (but more powerful) solution

But what if you do not want to consider the existence of `a_files` as equivalent to "*all files have been extracted*"? For instance, what if you want your Makefile to be robust against accidental deletion of some files?

The "*simple solution*" above does not untar again as long as the `../a_files` directory exists, even if its complete content has been deleted:

```
$ rm -rf ../a_files/*
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

A nice solution would thus be to consider the complete list of extracted files, not only their parent directory. If any one is missing you would untar again, else not. But things are a bit more difficult because we will need to:

1. Get the list of files. You can hard-wire the list in your Makefile but this is not very convenient. This list can also be computed automatically by looking at the tarball (`tar -tf <tarball>`), thanks to the GNU make `shell` function:

   ```
   LIST    := $(shell tar -tf ../a_files.tgz)
   ```
2. Tell make that all these files are created with one single execution of the `tar` recipe. This is not that easy because the natural make style is that one execution of a recipe creates one single file. And if we just declare that the tarball is a prerequisite of all extracted files:

   ```
   FILES   := $(addprefix ../,$(LIST))

   $(FILES): ../a_files.tgz
       tar -C .. -xvf $<
   ```

   make could decide to run as many `tar` recipes as there are files to extract. This is not what we want. Fortunately, pattern rules with multiple targets are an exception and we can exploit this. The tricky part is that we must replace at least one common character by `%` in all words of `$(FILES)`. Let's replace the `s` of `../a_files/XXX`:

   ```
   LIST    := $(patsubst a_files/%,%,$(shell tar -tf ../a_files.tgz))
   FILES   := $(addprefix ../a_files/,$(LIST))
   PATTERN := $(addprefix ../a_file%/,$(LIST))
   ```

   Now, our make variables will take values:

   ```
   LIST    :=  b/ b/b a
   FILES   := ../a_files/b/ ../a_files/b/b ../a_files/a
   PATTERN := ../a_file%/b/ ../a_file%/b/b ../a_file%/a
   ```

   And if we use `$(PATTERN)` as the target of a rule, make will consider that all matching targets, for any given same `%` replacement, are created by one single execution of the associated recipe.
3. Tell make that the last modification time of the files shall not be used to decide whether they are up to date or not with respect to the tarball. Order-only prerequisites, that we saw already in the first solution, are a way to do this.

All-in-all, the following should do what we want:

```
.PHONY: all

LIST    := $(patsubst a_files/%,%,$(shell tar -tf ../a_files.tgz))
FILES   := $(addprefix ../a_files/,$(LIST))
PATTERN := $(addprefix ../a_file%/,$(LIST))

all: $(FILES)

$(PATTERN): | ../a_files.tgz
    tar -C .. -xvf ../a_files.tgz
```

Demonstration:

```
$ make
tar -C .. -xvf ../a_files.tgz
a_files/
a_files/b/
a_files/b/b
a_files/a
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$ rm ../a_files/a
$ make
tar -C .. -xvf ../a_files.tgz
a_files/
a_files/b/
a_files/b/b
a_files/a
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment and feedback. I agree, in my haste I was incomplete in the question. I have several tar balls and I was hoping if I give a list I can extract the files from the corresponding tar file. So, I corrected FILES2 in my question to show the path to specific files in the tar ball. In the target $(FILES%), I was hoping that a list of files as in variable  FILES1, FILES2 will get extracted from the corresponding TAR_FILE1 and TAR_FILE2 using the corresponding EXTRACT_DIR and EXTRACT_LIST. I was incorrectly trying to make the association.

Comment: Did you solve your problem using one or the other solutions I suggested (or another)?